# Use dplyr to truncate top and bottom percentiles of a numeric variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I´ve generated a survey-weight. Because outlier survey-weights can lead to very big variances, i´m following a hint from many statistic books: I want to truncate the top 5% and bottom 5% of the survey weight.
I would like to use dplyr for this.

```
#generate data
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(sequence(2000),rnorm(2000,mean=3.16,sd=1.355686))) 
names(data)<-c("id","weight")

#This is how far i got
data2<-data %>% mutate(perc.weight=percent_rank(weight)) %>%
                mutate(perc.weight>0.95 | perc.weight<0.05)
```

After this, i´ve got two new variables. The first Variable gives percent-ranks of the weights. The second variable shows, if a value exceeds the aimed range.

Now, i want to replace the weights which are in the 95-100 percentile and the weights within the 0-5 percentile with the weight-values that constitute the border of those percentiles.

I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `quantile` function togehter with `pmin`, `pmax`:

```
data %>% mutate(weight_trunc = pmin(pmax(weight, quantile(weight, .05)), 
                                          quantile(weight, .95)))
```

Comment: If i may ask a follow-up question:

If i want to cut the weight in 10 parts of 10%-percentiles instead, and then use the mean of each percentile as weight. How would i do that?

Comment: @user2982730, you may want to check out dplyr's `ntile` function in case you don't know it yet. @shadow, nice answer! (+1)

Comment: I forgot, this is a solution for my second question in the comments: weight<-weight%>% 
  mutate(perc.weight=percent_rank(weight)) %>% 
   group_by(percentile=ntile(perc.weight,10)) 
weight<-weight.strata %>% mutate(percentile_mean=mean(weight))